# Averaging across list indicies during aggregation pipeline?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, pymongo

I currently have a MongoDB aggregation pipeline that ends with the following type of synthetic documents

```
[
    {
        '_id': '2019-09-10',
        'grouped_foos':
        [
            {... 'foo': [1, 78, 100]},
            {... 'foo': [8, 66, 98]},
            {... 'foo': [99, 5, 33]},
            {... 'foo': [120, 32, 2]}
        ]
    },
    {
        '_id': '2019-09-09',
        'grouped_foos':
        [
            {... 'foo': [10, 27]},
            {... 'foo': [19, 66]}
        ]
    },
    {
        '_id': '2019-09-08',
        'grouped_foos':
        [
            {... 'foo': [1]}
        ]
    }
]
```

I would like to continue this pipeline and average the indices of the `foo` lists together to form documents that look like

```
[
    {
        '_id': '2019-09-10',
        'avg_foo': [57, 45.25, 58.25]
    },
    {
        '_id': '2019-09-09',
        'avg_foo': [14.5, 46.5]
    },
    {
        '_id': '2019-09-08',
        'avg_foo': [1]
    }
]
```

**Is this type of averaging possible during aggregation?** Do I potentially need to `$unwind` the lists with indexing and assign new `_id` for uniqueness to make documents that look like

```
[
    {
        '_id': UUID,
        'old_id': '2019-09-10',
        'foo': 1,
        'index': 0
    },
    {
        '_id': UUID,
        'old_id': '2019-09-10',
        'foo': 78,
        'index': 1
    },
    ........
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you can try with `$unwind` but easier and faster approach would be to use [$reduce](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/reduce/index.html) to [$map](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/index.html) and [$sum](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/index.html) all the rows from `grouped_foos`. Then you'll be able to run another [$map](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/index.html) and use [$divide](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/divide/index.html) to get the average.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $project: {
            size: { $size: "$grouped_foos" },
            foo_sum: {
                $reduce: {
                    input: "$grouped_foos",
                    initialValue: [],
                    in: {
                        $map: {
                            input: { $range: [ 0, { $size: "$$this.foo" }, 1 ] },
                            as: "index",
                            in: {
                                $add: [
                                    { $arrayElemAt: [ "$$this.foo", "$$index" ] },
                                    { $ifNull: [ { $arrayElemAt: [ "$$value", "$$index" ] }, 0 ] }
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            _id: 1,
            avg_foo: {
                $map: {
                    input: "$foo_sum",
                    in: {
                        $divide: [ "$$this", "$size" ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/3xK23lXjLou)